# Qt Qml toLocaleString function returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, qt, date, qml, locale

I have the following JavaScript code to format the current date as a string:

```js
const date = new Date();
const options = { weekday: 'short', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
return date.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);
```

This should return *Wed 12:39* - and it does when it is executed in a web browser.

However, in Qt's JavaScript engine this returns a different value than expected, *4/5/23 12:39 PM*, which is including a date rather than a weekday, and using 12-hour rather than 24-hour time.

How do I make Qt format the date correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst not all areas of Qt/JS are up to date with industry JavaScript, the gap is closing. Because you're in Qt, you have the advantage of leveraging from, possibly, more rich `Qt.formatDateTime` method, e.g.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Label {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: -10
            radius: 10
            color: "lightsteelblue"
            z: -2
        }
        text: fn()
    }
    function fn() {
        const date = new Date();
        return Qt.formatDateTime(date, "ddd hh:mm AP"); // e.g. Thu 07:08 AM
    }
}
```

The `"hh"` can be either a 24-hour or 12-hour display. Because of the presence of `"AP"` it enforces the 12-hour display as well as appending AM/PM.

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABtnicZZDBTsMwDIbvfQqrp1aCrnABZeIwwQUJpA3tBdLETaMlzpQ6AoH27qRoKh349Pv3519OrD+GyLDjXbLqUNiLtnkMxDG4sdhKg/BVQK4X2aE766kkqSHEsVFIjPGZBBxlzHoGOqkOJoZEWsAbKpZkHC4CliG9de5fwBLwMhpLo4Drm/YCiFLblP0/tgouRAGls2bgkRFd5xKWF8xnTrudndOsGD9YQE9VXfwO+kSKbaAff/EKFWhk0JIRHoDwHZ6yrOr1DETkFCl/bdOH6CVP8731WE07V1BqrWEYhPew2Zb1GlYrwMY0sB8StHeivYfN6/mO0zc+Gnf4)

References:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#formatDateTime-method